# How to extract a property from an observable using a pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm trying to store an `OrderState` object in my ngrx store. The problem I have is extracting data from this to my UI. I just want to use the async pipe to get a child property from this observable object.

**order.state.ts**

```
export interface OrderState {
    stage: number;
    postcode: string;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
...
export class AppComponent {
  counter: Observable<number>;
  readonly orderState$: Observable<OrderState>;

    constructor(
      private appStateStore: Store<AppState>,
      private counterActions: CounterActions,

      private orderStateStore: Store<OrderState>,
      private orderActions: OrderActions,
    ) {

    this.counter = appStateStore.select('counter');
    this.orderState$ = orderStateStore.select(store => store);
    }
...
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>Stage: {{ (orderState$ | async)?.stage }}</div>
```

What is the syntax needed to get the `stage` property from my `orderstate` object.

If I display `{{ orderState$ }}` I just get `[Object object]` displayed on the page.

I'm guessing maybe I'm not selecting properly from my store?

---

Update: I must be missing something basic here. I've now done this to try and work out what is happening...

*app.component.ts*

```
stage: number

...

    this.orderStateStore.select(s => s).subscribe((data:OrderState) => {
      this.stage = data.stage;
      console.log(this.stage);
    });
```

*app.component.html*

```
<div>Stage: {{ stage }}</div>
```

I can see in the console my that stage reports as undefined. I believe this is connected to the problem. For some reason I cannot set the `stage` of my component from inside this arrow function.

---

Update: This behaviour seems very strange...

*order.state.ts*

```
export interface OrderState {
    stage: number;
    postcode: string;
}
```

*app.component.ts*

```
...
this.orderStateStore.select(s => s).subscribe((data:OrderState) => {      
  console.log('--- START ---');
  console.log(data);
  console.log('Stage: ' + data.stage);
  console.log('--- END ---');
});
...
```

Now here is what I get in the console...

[image]

As you can see, `data` is not actually of type `OrderState`. It is the wrapper type around `OrderState` called `AppState`. Fine, so I modify my code to log `data.orderState.stage` to get the value `1`. However, when I do this TypeScript complains that `orderState` is not a property of data - which it clearly is looking at the console output!

Comment: `{{ (orderState$ | async).stage }}` <== this syntax should work just fine.

Comment: Sadly not. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you should create plnkr with your example

Comment: @Meeker {{ (orderState$ | async)?.stage }} here null check is important it won't work without it.

Answer (score 3):

when you do {{ orderState$ }} it is displaying [Object object] because it is converting your result from async pipe (an object) to a string. To pull a certain property with a pipe you want to do something like this

```
 {{orderState$ | async | asyncField : 'stage'}}
```

where the pipe looks like

```
 @Pipe({name: 'asyncField'})
 export class AsyncFieldPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(object, key: string){
        return object[key];
     }
 }
```

So essentially you are passing the result from the async pipe to this pipe and returning a particular field. Here is a working plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/mnsf9s2zxEypDiDDUzrp?p=preview

---

**Update** - As an alternative to a pipe, you can also use the rjxs map method to limit what is returned from the observable sequence. I prefer this method since accessing a responses properties may not be as easy as the above pipe, in which case a more complex transform function may need to be included in the component.ts

```
this.orderState$ = orderStateStore.select(store => store).map(res => res.stage);
```

Here is a working plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/zbfuSBCLXwlMIhWCPf6z?p=preview

Comment: @RemotecUk an alternative to this pipe is to add a rjxs .map function to the end of your observable sequence .map(res => res.stage) now {{$orderState}} will just output the stage property

Comment: Could you provide an example of this in your answer at all as an alternative to the pipe? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Clearly I'm doing something wrong as that doesn't map anything into the value in the html.

Comment: @RemotecUk try console.logging the res in the map function to see what is happening to the value

Comment: No need to create a pipe to extract an attribute, simply use parentheses:
` {{ (orderState$ | async).stage }} `

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:
 {{(orderState$ | async).stage}}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was wrong the wrong selection from the ngrx store.

**WRONG**

```
this.orderState$ = orderStateStore.select(store => store);
```

**CORRECT**

```
this.orderState$ = appStateStore.select(x => x.orderState);
```

This is obvious in retrospect. My thinking was you could slice into the store where you wanted to. For reference my store objects are as follows:

**app.state.ts**

```
export interface AppState {
  counter: number;

  orderState : OrderState;
}
```

**order.state.ts**

```
export interface OrderState {
    stage: number;
    postcode: string;
}
```

`OrderState` is a "sub" store of `AppState`. In my case I still need to refer to the `appStateStore` but use the => function to retrieve the `orderState` from the object.